# How to write the locater for a pop-up element with just a 'span' and 'class' in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, cypress

So I am new to Cypress and trying a basic automation test. On the login page, there is an error popping up when the email is not in a valid format and I have to assert it but I am stuck in the test because I cannot get the error message. I cannot write a proper selector with the help of `cy.get()`
Below is the HTML for the pop-up from the page.

```
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="modal-overlay flex flex-col z-50 w-1/2" xpath="1">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex flex-col flex-1 mt-[70px]">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex flex-row justify-end">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex justify-between w-2/3 mr-2 p-5 bg-red-500">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex flex-col justify-center w-full">
<span data-v-666984d3="" class="font-normal md:text-md text-center flex-4 text-white">
        Email is not in a valid format.</span></div> 
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex justify-end p-2">
<a data-v-666984d3="" href="#" class="text-white">
<svg data-v-666984d3="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 
24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-6 w-6 text-white"><path data-v-666984d3="" stroke- 
linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
</path>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The page looks like this [Click Here Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxMVA.png)

And this is my code so far:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Negative Login Test Case', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://manager.xogo.io')
})
it('.should() - Verify the quick start guide is present', () => {
cy.get('.font-semibold')
.should('have.text', '\n        Got questions? Checkout our Quick Start Guide to see how 
it all works\n      ')
})
it('.type() - type email and password', () => {
cy.get('#email_1')
.type('ss@xogo.io').should('have.value','ss@xogo.io')
cy.get('#password_2')
.type('Balaji2022').should('have.value', 'Balaji2022')
})
it('.contains() - Click on the login button and get the pop-up', () => {
cy.get('button').contains('Login').click()
cy.get('span').should('have.class', 'font-normal md:text-md text-center flex-4 text- 
white')
.contains('    Email is not in a valid format.')
}) 
})
```

Any tips would be appreciated and an answer would be so good. Thanks my fellow coders for the help... Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also suggest to use:

```
cy.contains('Email is not in a valid format.').should('be.visible')
```

Also, one more thing try to ask in your team (better with devs) to include some custom attributes like `data-testId` in your code so you don't have to write complex selectors which over the time gets outdated and makes tests flaky. So your above mentioned code in the end it will look like this:

```
    <div data-v-666984d3="" class="modal-overlay flex flex-col z-50 w-1/2" xpath="1">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex flex-col flex-1 mt-[70px]">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex flex-row justify-end">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex justify-between w-2/3 mr-2 p-5 bg-red-500">
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex flex-col justify-center w-full">
<span data-v-666984d3="" data-testId='invalid_credentials_text' class="font-normal md:text-md text-center flex-4 text-white">
        Email is not in a valid format.</span></div> 
<div data-v-666984d3="" class="flex justify-end p-2">
<a data-v-666984d3="" href="#" class="text-white">
<svg data-v-666984d3="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 
24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-6 w-6 text-white"><path data-v-666984d3="" stroke- 
linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
</path>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Email is not in a valid format.').should('be.visible')
```

Forget about the classes, they are for formatting, will change over time, and will break your test. You just want to assert the error text is showing.